# Database structure, Users + User Types where Users can be of more than one Type

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I currently have a User table, `tblUser` and a User Types table, `tblUserTypes`.

The two are linked by means of a foreign key link in `tblUser... fkUserTypeID`.

Hence at the moment a user can be of only one type.

BUT, there are circumstances where the user can be of multiple types... say for example, a `Customer` as well as a `Supplier`.

The obvious solution to me is to create a new table in between `tblUser` and `tblUserTypes`, `tblUser_UserTypes` which is a bridging table:

```
[tblUser] ---< [tblUser_UserTypes] >--- [tblUserTypes]
```

BUT, I can see complexities arising from this... for example when exporting a list of users joined onto their user types, with a straight forward join I'm going to end up with multiple rows of those users. It could be possible to bring each user record back to a single row using a PIVOT query perhaps? (more below on this)

Importing Users into the system also seems problematic... I am currently using a `BCP` (Bulk Copy Process) from a file to import users directly into the user table... the import file contains a single field "user type" which works in the existing model because each user can currently only be of one type. BUT, with multiple user types I can't see how a direct BCP directly into the user table could work.

Adding to the complexity is that user types are not currently fixed... the table tblUserTypes is dynamic ... part of the system is to allow creation of any number of user types. However, there are some types of users that I need to know about to be able to define business logic at a higher level.... e.g. "Only allow users of type=x in this area"... so it has been suggested that in the user types table there is a series of flags that define what type of type the user types are (e.g. `IsCustomer`, `IsSupplier`)

This is feeling like an over complicated mess and I'm loosing sleep over how to move forward.

I would love to bring the user types back into the table `tblUser` and do away with the other two tables entirely... a series of checkboxes in the user table (e.g. `IsCustomer`, `IsSupplier`)... because that makes importing and exporting straight forward. BUT then the user types wouldn't be dynamic. Interestingly though the user types are not COMPLETELY dynamic... because as mentioned above there are some user types I need to know about when it comes to business login.

Hmmm, should it be a hybrid of the two? Am I trying to squash two features into one? Perhaps I could have checkbox / boolean types in the user table for the types that correlate to business logic  (e.g. `IsCustomer`, `IsSupplier`) and rename the context of the `"User Types"` to be `"User Groups"` or something like that.

A major concern for me is impact on importing, exporting and search results when considering a structure where a straight forward join is going to result in users being replicated... one row for each user type they belong to. I would have to do a PIVOT query to bring this back to one record per user, with a column for each user type, wouldn't I? A realistic example is a User table with 3 million records and importing 10,000 records at a time... or exporting 10,000 records at a time... or searching across those 3 million records to retrieve 3,000 matches and having that rendered on a web page in a paginated fashion where they can flick through the search result pages (I use `ROWNUM` in my search query to work with pagination, I don't return the whole lot every time).

This is my first question on Stack Overflow, I'm sorry if it's a bit convoluted or there are already answers listed... I tried to search but couldn't come up with examples handling the complexities of working with Users that can be of multiple Types.

Oh, in case it matters... this is a C# ASP.NET application working with SQL Server.

---

**After thinking it through and reading responses I'm going to go all the way and use the bridging table... the requirements say that users can be of multiple types so that's how it will be. Consequences on existing code are dramatic, but better now than down the track.**

I played around with the table structure and the queries required to get data out in a flat structure are a bit fiddly and ultimately require dynamic SQL (because the list of user types is dynamic) a which I'm not a fan of but I can't see another way to do it.

In the examples below companies fetched are filtered by an 'Event ID' i.e. fkEventID

If there is a better way to do the 'flattening' I would be very appreciative of any help :-)

**Straight forward join** (multiple rows per company if they are of more than one type)

```
select * from tblCompany 
left join tblCompany_CompanyType on fkCompanyID = pkCompanyID
left join tblCompanyType on fkCompanyTypeID = pkCompanyTypeID
where tblCompany.fkEventID = 1
```

**Hard Coded pivot query** (single rows per company if they are of more than one type, but the company types are not dynamic)

```
select * from (
select tblCompany.*,tblCompanyType.CompanyType from tblCompany left join
tblCompany_CompanyType on fkCompanyID = pkCompanyID
left join tblCompanyType on fkCompanyTypeID = pkCompanyTypeID
where tblCompany.fkEventID = 1
) AS sourcequery
Pivot (count(CompanyType) for CompanyType IN ([Customer],[Supplier],[Something Else])) as CompanyTypeName
```

**Dynamic Pivot Query** (multiple rows per company and handles dynamic company types)

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @sql  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = STUFF(
(SELECT N',' + QUOTENAME(CompanyType) AS [text()]
FROM (
select CompanyType from tblCompanyType
where fkEventID = 1
) AS Y
FOR XML PATH('')),
1, 1, N'');

SET @sql = N'SELECT * FROM (
select tblCompany.*,tblCompanyType.CompanyType from tblCompany left join tblCompany_CompanyType on fkCompanyID = pkCompanyID
left join tblCompanyType on fkCompanyTypeID = pkCompanyTypeID
where tblCompany.fkEventID = 1
) AS sourcequery
Pivot (count(CompanyType) for CompanyType IN (' + @cols + ')) as CompanyTypeName
order by pkCompanyID'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: Well for one, please stop putting the silly `tbl` prefix on tables. What else could it be, a view? So what? You're still going to treat it like a table. Just call it `dbo.Users`.

Comment: Also, how do you uniquely identify a user as *new* when you bulk import new users? If you import a new customer named John Smith, is that the same John Smith as the existing supplier named John Smith?

Comment: Finally, what is the problem with the same user coming back multiple times? You can always filter by user type, or just have the application / presentation tier collapse multiple rows for the same user.

Comment: Do you also prefix your user defined stored procedures with `sp_`?

Comment: Old habits die hard I suppose... I still prefix everything! Was taught this many years ago, helps when reading any sort of code, stored procedures, c# code, whatever... txtUser is a textbox, strUser is a string, tblUser is a table. Maybe comes from the days of notepad code writing where everything was black text.

Comment: Yes... the import process might get complicated regarding duplicates, I'm not sure how to handle that at the moment, a file being imported might have a mixture of duplicates that are literally duplicates that shouldn't be imported, and others that need to be merged with existing.

I think in some cases I can get away with listing the user multiple times (I'll push for it where possible!)... but there are definitely cases where the requirement is to return only one user row, hard work on the presentation layer if it's a file export of many records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You truly do have a many to many relationship between users and user types, and I suggest you go ahead and implement it that way.

If you have a need to see it flattened out in some instances, you can accomodate that with a view or stored procedure.

If you want to continue to import using BCP, you can always BCP into a staging table and then use a stored proc to fill out your 3 tables. It's probably safer to do it that way anyway.

Keeping to fully implementing the many to many relationship will give you the most flexibility in your app, and will prevent you from needing to continually modify your user table as you get new requirements for new security roles.

Comment: You're right. I'm being lazy trying to avoid going all the way with this... I've got a lot of code already developed and this core entity structure change is going to rock the boat majorly!... but i'm going to have to chalk this one up to poor planning and take it on the chin.

I'll do as you suggest re: BCPing the file into a staging table and work with it from there.

Will post an answer with the PIVOT query structure I'm planning on using to flatten the data out where needed... might help someone else out.